# Help with solutions of $ x|x|-6x+7=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I rewrote as $$x= \pm \frac{6x-7}{x}$$and then solved for plus or minus, rewriting again and using the quadratic formula. I found $$1,-7,3\pm\sqrt{2}$$ However, my book says  that 1 isn't a solution, why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $x\ge0$

$x^2 - 6x + 7 = 0\\
x = 3 \pm \sqrt 2$

Suppose $x<0$ then $|x| = -x$

$-x^2 - 6x + 7 = 0\\
-(x-1)(x+7) = 0$

$x = 1$ is not consistent with the assumption $x< 0$ and must be discarded.

Answer (score 3):

One can consider two cases:
$$\begin{cases}x\ge 0\\x^2-6x+7\end{cases}\quad \rightarrow \boxed{x=3\pm\sqrt2},$$
and
$$\begin{cases}x<0\\x^2+6x-7 = 0\end{cases}\quad\rightarrow \begin{cases}x<0\\x\in\{1, -7\}\end{cases}\quad \boxed{x=-7}.$$

The error in the responses is due to the fact that the possible roots did not match the domain of permissible solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You found that $x = 1$ is a solution to $x^2 + 6x - 7 =0$. However, this is only equivalent to $x|x| - 6x +7 = 0$ when $x \le 0$. Thus $x = 1 > 0$ is not a solution to $x|x| - 6x - 7 =0$.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the simplest way is to consider two cases, whenever $x\ge 0$ or $x<0$. In both cases we have quadratic equations. Be careful and compare their solutions with the domains of these cases.